# Anyway to get compilation flags used in building a .class file?

Tags: java, build, compilation, flags

I have a bunch of `.class` files that I did not myself build.

From these `.class` files, is it possible to know the various compilation flags used for building them? Things like... optimization on or off, with debug info on or off, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No major Java compiler does any kind of optimizations (except for some constant value folding). That's usually reserved for the JVM to be done at runtime.

To find out if a `.class` was generated with or without debug info, run `javap` on it using the `-v` flag and look for the `LineNumberTable` attribute. They should look something like this:

```
  LineNumberTable: 
   line 7: 0
   line 8: 8
```

If the class was compiled with full debugging info (including local variables), then it also contains a `LocalVariableTable` like this:

```
  LocalVariableTable: 
   Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
   0      9      0    argc       [Ljava/lang/String;
```

One compiler flag that actually influences the output is `-encoding` to specify the input source file encoding. Since string literals in `.class` files always use UTF-8, there's no way to detect the original source files encoding from the `.class` file.